# Setting Python Version 3 on the Path

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/ml-data-preparation-sandbox$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/bin/python2.7 (part of link group python) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
There are 3 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.7   4         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.7   4         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.9   3         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/python3.7 because link group python is broken
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/ml-data-preparation-sandbox$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

How can I set Python3.7 as the default? Should I change the priority? To use Zeppelin 0.10.0 I guess I need Python 3.7.

EDIT: I installed pyenv and I have the following now:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ which python
/home/joesan/.pyenv/shims/python
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ python --version
Python 3.7.8
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.7.8 (set by /home/joesan/.pyenv/version)
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$
```

Comment: The star says 3.7 already is the current one... Use `python --version`

Comment: Also, looking at your previous question, `zeppelin.python` is using a hard-coded `/usr/bin/python`, not the value `python` itself. Only in the later case, does the PATH actual matter

Comment: You can see that python3 --version gives Python 3.8.10 which is actually my problem!

Comment: That's not really a problem with Zeppelin, though, but you should be doing `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

Comment: Why not using an environment manager like [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)?

Comment: In other words, change Zeppelin's Python interpreter settings to use `/usr/bin/python3.7`, and you will solve **that** problem. You don't need to modify OS level settings to fix Zeppelin

Comment: It did not work. Still getting the same problem! This is so annoying!

Comment: What happened when you tried `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`?

Comment: Do `which python3`.  Maybe you have a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` that is interfering.

Comment: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3

Comment: @joesan Please [edit] the question to add that. Next, what OS are you using? With Ubuntu for example, different versions of Python are not alternatives. You could use a virtual env in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O, boy. Please consider using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). You will be able to use as many python versions as you need.

Comment: I played around with it, but did not solve my problem. Have a look at my original post above!

Comment: Finally I managed to get this solved. Thanks a ton for recommending pyenv!